# Mavericks - User Account unavailable at login

Tags: macos, user-account, accounts

I have a Macbook Pro running Mavericks. I was using it just fine, stepped away and it had gone into powersave mode. Upon my return I turned it back on, no response, so I held the power down for a short while and then rebooted. Now my user account is missing. I can see Administrator or Guest.

This is a company supplied Macbook so I don't have the administrator password.

Any ideas as to what has happened? I can see my user folder is still there is I login as Guest.

Comment: Did you tried to turn it on and off again? If the account doesn't appears then you want be able to recover without a adminstrator password. (Which basically is really easy to reset)

Comment: Er yeah, cold booted the thing. Have just run a disk and permission repair but that's not really helped.

Comment: Is FireVault2 enabled on the disk?

Comment: Issue resolved. Had to Rm to plist and recreate the account. No Firevault enabled.

Answer (score 1):

Issue resolved. Had to RM the plist and recreate the account. No Firevault enabled.